# Floated div not expanding to 100%

Tags: css

I know that this is not an uncommon problem, as a bit of Googling threw up quite a few pages with similar problems to my own. But try as I might I can't fix it so here goes:

I am currently building the website to my rugby team. It has a two column layout, with a main area and a sidebar. The relevant HTML is roughly

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="maincolumn"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

From some of the websites, I have gleaned that I need to set body and html to 100% and all the containers, so I have:

```css
html, body, #wrapper, #innerwrapper, #sidebar { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; 
#wrapper { max-width:900px; margin:0 auto; width:90%; }
#sidebar { float: right; width: 35%; padding:2%; background-color:#f7f7f7; }
#maincolumn { width:56%; float:left; padding-right:5%; }
.clear { clear:both; }
```

The problem I am having, is that when #maincolumn has a lot of content, the sidebar does not expand all the way down to the bottom of the page which is the behaviour I would like. I made some progress by setting all the containers to 100% and then adding the clear element, but that still only expands it a short way.

Comment: JSFiddle for a faster answer

Comment: the title should read 'how to set all column divs to same height'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of floating, you can use CSS tables:

```css
#wrapper {
    display: table;
}
#sidebar, #maincolumn {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fXtE/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="maincolumn">vgnhngbbv hbcv nfvfbngbc</div>
    <div id="sidebar">dfrtnjnbc ghm gbgfnbvfnythgfbbfg</div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
html, body, #wrapper, #maincolumn, #sidebar { height: 100%; min-height: 100%;}
#wrapper { max-width:900px; margin:0 auto; width:90%; }
#sidebar { float: right; width: 35%; padding:2%; background-color:#f7f7f7; }
#maincolumn { width:56%; float:left; padding:2%; background-color:#ff0000; }
.clear { clear:both;  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ283/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want both columns to have the same height regardless of the amount of content within them, first you have to understand that setting `height:100%` sets the height in relation to the width of the parent div(or containing block).

So if that's the case, here's what you can do:

```
#wrapper{
height:900px;
}
#sidebar{
height:100%;
}
#maincolumn{
height:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2TfcT/)