# Display: table-cell floated DIV height expanding to 100% only working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I asked a question before and thought I had gotten a good result. The link to the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470076/floated-div-not-expanding-to-100). Essentially, I was asking how to cause a floated DIV to expand to 100% of its parent divs when the content of said parent was larger than the floated DIV.

The answer I accepted (using display:table and display:table-cell on the parent and the DIV respectively) works fine on Chrome, but I have just discovered that it doesn't work at all on Firefox and Safari.

Has anyone got any idea of what I can do to rectify this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the off-chance that the code you now have isn't completely identical to the accepted answer, could you reproduce it (in a new fiddle, even)?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
div { display: table}
div > div { display: table-row}
div > div > div  { display: table-cell}
```